# Angular Controller invoke from different module controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I'm trying to invoke one controller from another controller. Both are in different modules.

```
var app = angular.module("WorkflowBuilder", ["ax.workflow.builder"] );
```

WorkflowBuilder is a module where controller below is located:

```
var AxProjectsWeb = angular.module('WorkflowBuilder', ['angularModalService', 'sticky', 'leaflet-directive', 'ui.bootstrap', 'nya.bootstrap.select', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);

AxProjectsWeb.controller('KnowledgeController2',function(){});
```

So controller KnowledgeController2 is the one I would like to invoke in a controller below:

```
(function (ax, ng) {

    ng.module('ax.webagent.survey').directive('axSurveyFieldKnowledgeBase', AxSurveyFieldKnowledgeBase); // Name must be lowercase!!!

    function AxSurveyFieldKnowledgeBase() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                // We don't want long names :)
                axC: '=axControl', // Bi-directional binding - to można zapodawac do kązdej dyrektywy - definiuje jak są ich wartości bindowane
                li18n: '=axI18n',
                isReadonly: '=axIsReadonly'
            },
            link: link,
            templateUrl: '../../../WorkflowBuilder/templates/survey/fields/AxSurveyFieldKnowledgeBase.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: ['$controller', '$scope', 'Helpers', controller]
        }
    }

    function controller($controller, $scope, helpers) {
        var KnowledgeController2 = $scope.$new();
        var knC = $controller('KnowledgeController2', { $scope: KnowledgeController2 });

    }
});
```

The error i recieve is :

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/ng/areq?p0=KnowledgeController2&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at pb (http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:22:41)
    at Sa (http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:22:128)
    at b.$get (http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:80:25)
    at new controller (http://localhost:54486/WorkflowBuilder/js/survey/fields/axSurveyFieldKnowledgeBase.js:32:19)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:96)
    at b.$get.Q.instance (http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:80:151)
    at K (http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:61:140)
    at http://localhost:54486/Scripts/angular.min.js:68:475
```

Comment: you cannot inject one controller into another. What is it that you have to do exactly? You may be thinking about architecture incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the 2 1st snippets.

You declare twice the same module with differents dependencies.

One will be ignored, guess the one ignored is where you controller was defined.
Move the dependency ["ax.workflow.builder"] with the others.

Comment: I did it. It doesn't change anything actually

Comment: did you remove the 2nd argument from the 1st snippet or did you let an empty array ? If youle tan empty array, remove it. And check if you didn't do the same for that module or others in your file, for each module you  must have only one angular.module with the 2nd argument sets (the dependencies)